# For submiting HTML form data should I use the variable, "id", or "name"

Tags: python, html, forms, python-3.x

I am trying to submit a form via python and I need to know, should I use the "id" value, or the "name" value. They are both different.

Comment: Usually it is `name`, but we'll never know without having more information: the code you have so far, the HTML code of the form or a url where we can see it.

Comment: Well, if you submitted the form with a browser, what would the browser use? (Hint: name.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the "name" attribute.

For example using radio buttons, each button will have the same name but different Id. When submitted only the one with a value (the selected one) will be submitted.